# How to simplify SQL select command

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query is taking too long time for execution. Please help me to simplify?
Here is my query:

```
     SELECT uid,etop_id,SUM(amount) AS amt,
                    (SELECT m_name FROM member_details WHERE etop_id=a.etop_id) AS m_name,
                    (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM hidden_charges WHERE etop_id=a.etop_id 

    AND entry_date BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2 AND particular IS NULL
                    ) AS hidden,
                    (SELECT (SUM(credit)-SUM(debit)) 
                        FROM member_transaction
                        WHERE member_id=a.uid 
                        AND is_succeed=1 
                        AND isnull(reference_id,0) NOT IN( SELECT 
user_reference_id FROM recharge_request WHERE status=7)
                    ) AS balance,
                    (   SELECT TOP 1 credit 
                        FROM member_transaction 
                        WHERE member_id=a.uid 
                        AND credit>0 
                        AND entry_date=(SELECT MAX(entry_date) 
                                        FROM member_transaction 
                                        WHERE member_id=a.uid AND credit>0)) AS credit 
            FROM recharge_request a WHERE status=1 AND rdate BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2 
            GROUP BY etop_id, uid ORDER BY amt DESC
```

Comment: Are you aware of the possible sql-injection?

Comment: Yes I'm replace text boxes with parameters.

Comment: @AmitMishra . . . Simplify the query by removing clauses to figure out what is taking so long.  Then ask another question with the simplified query.

Comment: @Amit Mishra, Please post the schema of table and test data to help you. Please refer to this ling on how to post on forum. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

For large queries I tend to pop data into a temp table and use that to query.

```
Select * 
Into #Table
From member_transaction 
Where member_id=a.uid
```

Then just query #Table instead of member_transaction, should speed things up.